# Backup of 5TB server

Tags: linux, backup, automation, deduplication, linux-server

I'm looking for a software that will help me backup a server with 5TB of data. My wishlist:

- Backup on 1-2TB SATA disks
- Should need little to no configuration (just the directories to backup and the slot of my RAID system where it can find a backup disk)
- No or smart compression (most data is audio and video files)
- Easy restore of all data
- Backup should start by switching drives
- Software should make sure that the backups are redundant enough (so that failing sectors of a disk don't mean data loss)
- When I rename/move a file, it should notice and just record the change (instead of backing up the whole file again). Or maybe automatic deduplication.
- Spin down the backup drive when it doesn't need it to extend disk life
- It should keep deleted files for a period of time but I also need an option to purge files more quickly
- I'd prefer if it kept files together (so if they are in the same directory, they should also end up on the same disk). Maybe it should use *two* backup disks: One with all incremental changes and then one with an archive.

Anything you could recommend?

[EDIT] I'm on Linux :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Acronis

http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/server-linux/

Comment: The feature list sounds good; only the price is prohibitive for my use case.

Comment: Hopefully someone will post an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I assume you use Windows OS?
Try Symantec backup system recovery desktop/server edition depends what OS you have.
Other good program is ViceVersa.
Both of them has trial, and you can try it before you buy it.
Hope it helps:)

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job to do the backup. In my server, I just TAR everything needed to be backup to other data storage server via network every night. After a successful TAR action, I delete the old copy of backup.

In your case, I think it takes more than a night to backup all your data. Are your files being changed frequently? If only a small part of the 5TB is changed, consider the use of FTP instead of cp. Only overwrites the files that is needed to be transferred. More, FTP scripts are not difficult to be written.

Give it a try. Work / Not Working ? Tell us after try.

Comment: Since there is no way to fit the data on a single disk, I need a program which can distribute the backups on several disks which aren't connected to the PC all the time.

Comment: Interesting. My solution is still valid, but you have to split the TAR action. Set different time to run the cron job, when the related external hard disk is online. Or you can execute the TAR scripts manually.

Comment: Why this doesn't work for me: too much hassle and too inefficient. I want deduplication. I want cheap snapshots. I want easy recovery. And most of all, I want a ready solution, rather than a programming tool. There are plenty of Windows packages that have these, now just need to find one for a headless linux server...

Comment: Still not matching the requestion from the OP, but WTF? Tar?  I like tar, but in G-ds name if you suggest something like that start with `rsync`, which would only copy over changes. With tars you would be doing full backups, and a 5TB full backup will take almost a day.

Answer (score 0):

©XSIBackup is free to be used in Linux. It features differential replication and backup with deduplication at block level. It includes a FUSE file system that you can use to mount the virtually unlimited number of mount points to extract individual files.

Yo can download it from Sourceforge.net:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsibackup-app/files/